# how to pass two parameter in bash single line?

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

Suppose I have a command which require two parameter, such as

```
bismark -1 R1_1.fastq -2 R1_2.fastq
```

And actually, R1_1.fastq and R1_2.fastq can be obtain with

```
ls *fastq | paste - -
```

or can be obtain with

```
echo samplelist.txt
```

my question is how to merge these two command into one line?

```
ls *fastq | paste - - | xargs -n 2 | bismark -1 {} -2 {}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
while read f g
do
  bismark -1 "$f" -2 "$g"
done < samplelist.txt
```

Or:

```
xargs -n2 sh -c 'bismark -1 "$1" -2 "$2"' . < samplelist.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With an array, it would be simple:

```
a=(*fastq) ;  bismark -1 "${a[0]}" -2 "${a[1]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you would do:

```
ls *fastq | parallel -N2 bismark -1 {1} -2 {2}
```